# Android - Load image byte by byte in imageview

Tags: android, image, file

I have a large size of the image file which is nearly 16MB size. I want to load this image in my imageView and zoom it after that add markers. I tried this with  **subsampling-scale-image-view**.  I am following the below  link https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view .

The important point is I am loading image from url. The above library not supporting that. So I just downloaded the image and save to  SD card after that load from that local file. Technically which is working.

**Issue:**

Now the issue is it is taking too much of time for the first time downloading. Also even second time it takes nearly a minute.

**My Idea:**

Due to this issue, I try to load image byte by byte. Once the image is downloading 100bytes then show that in imageView next download the next part of the image from url. Is it possible to doing like that?

Currently I am loading image like the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(url_);

                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root+"/"+ fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        image.setImage(ImageSource.uri(root+"/"+ fileName));
                    }
                });
```

Can somebody help me to solve this riddle?

**Note:** **If there are any possibilities other than this library pls add your suggestions**.

Comment: Is it come from API? i mean images

Comment: Yes it is from the API

Comment: Ask php developer to convert image to timthumb or mthumb format

Comment: That is not possible check my question. I want to zoom that image and add markers in that. So I can't use thumb.

Comment: I think you loaded file directly  from server that why it take time to load images,Just convert images to timthmub then you can pass height ,width and quallity then get image which quality you want

Comment: The image is nearly 16MB so only it is taking that much time.

Comment: no bro if images convert timthumb format then image is low size without disturb your qality

Comment: Even with that the image size can be reduced. But anyway we might need to face this issue right. Maybe we can reduce the loading time 100 seconds to 70 seconds that's all right?

Comment: I just want do without any conversion. That is the ultimate issue..

Comment: How about image caching? Maybe you could cache the image to lower the loading time in subsequent requests.

Comment: @PrerakSola Any idea is appreciated. If you share any sample link that will be helpful for me..

Comment: You can extract the data and set to imageview like this right  Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  ..This will get rid of the file saving time

Comment: You could pass the `Cache-Control` header in the request like: `connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));`.  The unit for `max-age` is **seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this but you can check if this work.

Get the data from url in form of byte Array.

```
data = getImageStream(url);  //should call in async Task..
```

Now convert byte array into bitmap and set in imageView.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
 image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Not writing into file.This will help with some performance improvement.

```
public byte[] getImageStream(String url){      
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = url.openStream ();
  byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
  int n;

  while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
    baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
  }
}
catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.printf ("Failed while reading bytes from %s: %s", url.toExternalForm(), e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace ();
  // Perform any other exception handling that's appropriate.
}
finally {
  if (is != null) { is.close(); }
}
return baos.toByteArray();
}
```